Implementing Server-Side Pagination and Exporting Filtered Data in Laravel Bootstrap Tables
I am developing a feature for data export using Bootstrap Tables in my Laravel application. The data displayed in the Bootstrap table is sourced from an API endpoint in Laravel. The problem arises when I attempt to export the data to PDF, Excel, or CSV formats. Regardless of whether a custom date filter is applied to the table, only the first 10 rows (corresponding to the first page) are exported. How can I ensure that all filtered data, beyond just the first page, is properly exported to these file formats?
The code I tried is as below:
The custom date filter form:
<div class="form-inline filter_asset_by_date">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="start_date">{{ trans('admin/asset_maintenances/form.start_date') }}</label>
            <input type="date" id="start_date" class="form-control" name="start_date">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="completion_date">{{ trans('admin/asset_maintenances/form.completion_date') }}</label>
            <input type="date" id="completion_date" class="form-control" name="completion_date">
          </div>
          <button id="reset_filters" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
        </div>

The table:
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table
                    data-cookie-id-table="maintenancesReport"
                    data-pagination="true"
                    data-show-footer="true"
                    data-id-table="maintenancesReport"
                    data-search="true"
                    data-side-pagination="server"
                    data-show-columns="true"
                    data-show-export="true"
                    data-show-refresh="true"
                    data-sort-order="asc"
                    id="maintenancesReport"
                    data-url="{{ route('api.maintenances.index') }}"
                    class="table table-striped snipe-table"
                    data-export-options='{
                        "fileName": "maintenance-report-{{ date('Y-m-d') }}",
                        "ignoreColumn": ["actions","image","change","checkbox","checkincheckout","icon"]
                        }'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="company" data-sortable="false" data-visible="false" data-formatter="companiesLinkObjFormatter">{{ trans('admin/companies/table.title') }}</th>
                    <th data-sortable="true" data-field="id" data-visible="false">{{ trans('general.id') }}</th>
                    <th data-sortable="true" data-field="asset_tag" data-formatter="assetTagLinkFormatter" data-visible="false">{{ trans('general.asset_tag') }}</th>
                    
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

The jquery code I am using is :
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.filter_asset_by_date').on('change', function() {
              var startDate = $('#start_date').val();
              var endDate = $('#completion_date').val();

              $('#maintenancesReport').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                  query: {
                      start_date: startDate,
                      completion_date: endDate
                  },
                  exportDataType: 'all'
              });
          });
          $('#reset_filters').on('click', function() {
              $('#start_date').val('');
              $('#completion_date').val('');
              $('#maintenancesReport').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                  query: {
                      start_date: '',
                      completion_date: ''
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  </script>

The date range filter is working properly and is showing the data as per the filters applied but when the export is clicked only first 10 rows are exported only.
My controller code for the api is :
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('view', Asset::class);

        $maintenances = AssetMaintenance::select('asset_maintenances.*')->with('asset', 'asset.model', 'asset.location', 'supplier', 'asset.company', 'admin');

    
        if ($request->filled('start_date')) {
            $maintenances->whereDate('start_date', '>=', $request->input('start_date'));
        }
    
        if ($request->filled('completion_date')) {
            $maintenances->whereDate('completion_date', '<=', $request->input('completion_date'));
        }

        $offset = (($maintenances) && ($request->get('offset') > $maintenances->count())) ? $maintenances->count() : $request->get('offset', 0);

        // Check to make sure the limit is not higher than the max allowed
        ((config('app.max_results') >= $request->input('limit')) && ($request->filled('limit'))) ? $limit = $request->input('limit') : $limit = config('app.max_results');
        $total = $maintenances->count();
        $maintenances = $maintenances->skip($offset)->take($limit)->get();
        return (new AssetMaintenancesTransformer())->transformAssetMaintenances($maintenances, $total);


    }

I now want the filtered results to be exported properly

Is the index() method responsible for Exporting as well? If so, you've got ->skip($offset)->take($limit) included there, so of course it wouldn't include everything. (Sidenote, where are $offset and $limit defined? There's no $offset = ... in your code). You might need to edit your question and include more details; it's a little unclear what is happening where.

@TimLewis I have added the offset logic handling part. The index method is responsible for the results showing only. The export thing is been done by bootstrap-tables own export functionality.

One of the core devs of the bootstrap-table here.
By default the exportDataType option of the export plugin will use basic, which means only the shown entries in the table will be exported.
If you change that option to all the pagination will be temporary turned off and the whole dataset returned by the api endpoint will be exported.
For larger datasets we suggest to implement the export youreself anyways.

@DustinUtecht I also used the laravel excel instead of using bootstrap export and now all things are working perfect
